# HLM to ANOVA model

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I am conducting analysis involving classroom data. I have a moderately small dataset with 22 classes and 280 total students. I'm trying to see if one type of lesson worked better than another, and if it there are gender differences. Does the following progression make sense?

## 1. Check the ICC to determine if hierarchical modeling is appropriate.

Using `lmer` results I manually calculated the ICC by looking at the intercept variance and residual variance. The ICC is low, there isn't variation explained by class.

```
>lmer(ss_gain ~ 1 + (1 | class), hlm_dat)
Random effects:
  Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
  class    (Intercept) 1.906e-19 4.366e-10
  Residual             7.169e-01 8.467e-01
Number of obs: 282, groups:  class, 22
>(1.906e-19)/(1.906e-19 + 7.169e-01)
[1] 2.658669e-19
```

## 2. Because the ICC is so low, I fit with fixed effects.

Even though I know there isn't much variation explained by `class` I included it as a control variable in addition to `gender` and `Treatment`. Both are binary variables:

- gender: 0 = male, 1 = female
- Treatment: 0 = traditional lesson, 1 = new lesson

Here's the model:

```
>ss_mod_1 <- aov(ss_gain ~ class + gender*Treatment, data = dat)
>summary(ss_mod_1)`
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
class             21  19.76  0.9411   1.337  0.151
gender             1   0.07  0.0682   0.097  0.756
gender:Treatment   1   0.02  0.0203   0.029  0.865
Residuals        258 181.58  0.7038
```

Here `Treatment` is dropped from these results. Each class was taught the same lesson type so with `class` in the model it is unnecessary. Because I'm interested in `Treatment`, not necessarily `class` differences I decide to drop it from the model so that `Treatment` will be listed.

## 3. I drop `class` from the model so that `Treatment` will be shown.

The final model I fit is:

```
>ss_mod_2 <- aov(ss_gain ~ gender*Treatment, data = dat)
```

Does this progression from HLM to ANOVA and then ANOVA without my control variable make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by each class was taught the same lesson type? I don't understand why Treatment is missing from ss_mod_1. All the classes had the same type of lesson plan? Another point, that the ICC is low does not mean you have to model it as a fixed effect model. A better reason for that would be the relatively small number of clusters, though the small ICC means you can model it as a fixed effect model.

Comment: What I mean was that everyone in each class had the same lesson. And there are two types of lesson. I was surprised that it disappears (you can see from the model it isn't my doing) but that's the only thing I can think of to explain why it happens.

Comment: Given this, your final model makes sense. I would plot the interaction to understand what is going on. I would probably run a class only model, and a treatment only model in between. And maybe a no interaction model also. There is usually something to be learned from modeling in gradual steps.

Comment: And you identified the problem, it was perfect collinearity, so R automatically dropped the treatment variable.